# The requested URL was not found on ubuntu 18

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu, yii

I'm using Yii 1, and moving it to AWS.

On my server Yii is installed in `/var/www/html`

When I go to my URL, I get a 404 error.

below is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend/www
        
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
 </VirtualHost>
```

And my `.htaccess` file is located in my `/var/www/html/frontend/www`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /html/frontend/www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /html/frontend/www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase /html/frontend/www/`? This should not be necessary if you configured `DocumentRoot`  as `/var/www/html/frontend/www`. Same for `RewriteRule . /html/frontend/www/index.php [L]` - it should be just `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`.

Comment: ok, i removed `RewriteBase /html/frontend/www/` and change this `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I added this in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

now it works, and i can view sub directories in my url

Answer (score 0):

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend/www
        <Directory /var/www/html/frontend/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

check your index.php is called or not?